# Где поставить запятую в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Печорин имеет особенную черту такую как безразличие к жизни.

Answer (score 1):

**Изменил ответ 1 декабря 2020 г.**

*1. Печорин имеет особенную черту, такую, как безразличие к жизни.*

Составной союз *"такая, как"* поясняет словосочетание *"отличительная черта".*

Запятую внутри этого составного союза меня заставил поставить пример с [Нацкорпуса](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&endyear=2019&nodia=1&docid=L3BsYWNlL3J1c2NvcnBvcmEvdGV4dHMvZmluYWxpemVkL21haW4vc291cmNlL3Bvc3QxOTUwL2ZpY3Rpb25fbWVtL2hhbGZpbmEvaGFsZmluMDYueG1sIzAwMDQ=):

> Если ему требовалась жена для хозяйства, нужно было поискать себе хорошую домохозяйку, такую, как Феня. [М. Л. Халфина. Милочка (1970-1980)]

"Такую, как Феня" предстаёт уточнением предыдущей части фразы и отделяется запятой. Указательное слово и союз тоже разделяются запятой.

*2. Печорин имеет особенную черту, такую как безразличие к жизни.*

Вариант без запятой можно оправдать схожестью с "а именно" и другие, но принципиально не отличающиеся, на мой взгляд, примеры с [Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722):

> Погода дождливая, такая как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, такая как в старинных замках.

3. При всём сказанном я бы скорее изменил предложение и поставил "такую" перед определяемым словосочетанием:

*Печорин имеет такую особенную черту, как безразличие к жизни.*

**Вывод**

Я не знаю, как правильно, с запятой или без между частями союза, если не переставлять слова, но если на этот случай действительно действует то же правило, что и в примерах с Грамоты, то я бы выбрал вариант без запятой (второй).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не мог минут 10 разобраться.

Comment: Не за что) Кстати, если правильно писать, то в вашей фразе лучше 10 написать словом. Если единицы измерения после числа (без приблизительного значения), тогда можно и числом.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой тот случай когда хвостовые нули - значащие цифры) 2000 лет назад значит больше 1999 лет назад и меньше 2001 года назад. а 2 тыс лет назад значит больше 1.5 тыс лет назад и меньше 2.5 тыс лет назад) причём полагаю это всех языков касается, не только русского. но "10" - короче писать)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой а я бы тут вообще не зпт а тире фиганул - чтоб подчеркнуть что это не сравнение ("такую как эта" = "подобную этой") и не частный случай ("такую как эта" = "стоящую в одном ряду с этой") а объяснение мол "такую как" = "а именно следующую". мне вообще кажется тут "такую как" - лишнее - создаёт ощущение сравнения или частного случая. как думаете?

Comment: @whyer: да нет, не лишнее оно, и тире тут не подойдёт.

Comment: Кстати, собачка тут не нужна вам: когда пишут комментарии к чьему-то вопросу или ответу, автор и так получает уведомления.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой какое вообще значение у "такой как"? не нашёл в словарях - может вы лучше умеете искать и найдёте? насколько я знаю, это синоним "например" - разве нет? а тут ведь не пример а пояснение. почему оно подходит тут?

Comment: А чего вы упорно собачку ставите? Можно просто по имени. "Такой как" используется, когда надо пояснить предыдущее понятие, это то же самое, что и "а именно". Сейчас подправлю ответ и ссылку дам.